# Resize web page to fit the browser window using pure javascript

Tags: javascript, resize, scale

I have a simple page like this:

```
<html>
<body>

<h1>Table</h1>

 <table>
  <tr>
    <th>row1</th>
    <th>row2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>text1</td>
    <td>text2</td>
  </tr>
</table> 

</body>
</html>
```

Now, what i try to do is i try to scale this simple table, when i resize the browser window. I know it can be done using transform and jquery like so:

```
function updateScale() {

    var ww = $win.width();
    var wh = $win.height();
    var newScale = 1;

    // compare ratios
    if(ww/wh < baseSize.w/baseSize.h) { // tall ratio
        newScale = ww / baseSize.w;
    } else { // wide ratio
        newScale = wh / baseSize.h;        
    }

    $lay.css('transform', 'scale(' + newScale + ',' +  newScale + ')');

    console.log(newScale);
}

$(window).resize(updateScale);
```

But how do i scale it using pure javascript? Should i just recalculate width/height? Or i have to scale every `td` too? My goal is to proportianaly scale the website to fit the browser window, but i want to do this in pure javascript, and that's where i don't understand what properties i should change when `resize` event fired.

Comment: Can you include all relevant source code please? Trying to use this throw undefined for multiple variables such as `$win` and `baseSize`. Thank you

Comment: @NewToJS please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30115468/proportionally-scale-website-to-fit-browser-window this code works, but i want to do it without transofrm and jquery. The goal is to make pure javascript scaling of the web page

Comment: Do you mean something like this? [**JsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/New_To_JS/2h36zsdm/)

Comment: @NewToJS yes exactly, but not using tranfsofrm/jquery

Comment: Not sure how you plan to do this without transform since that is a `css` property to enable exactly what you want but this is very possible to replace the `jQuery`, it will just take time to replace the functions with pure `javascript`

Comment: @NewToJS i know this property does the trick but its not supported on older IE browsers, i need to support them. Can you lead me in the right direction? let's say i have the  newScale calculated in `updateScale()` now instead of changing transform, i need to recalculate table size, so when the windows is smaller, the table width and height are actually big values

Comment: No `jQuery` but it does still use `transform` [**JsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/New_To_JS/b0z2ujfn/)

Comment: Maybe this **Blog Post:** [**How to Enable CSS Transform in IE6-8**](https://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css-transform-ie/) might also be of some use?

Comment: @NewToJS yeah that certainly works. any idea how can i do it without external libs? I mean it should not be that hard, but i can't get my head arount how to correctly produce resulting width/height based on ratio

Comment: I must be missing something. Does op just want the table to take up the whole vieport? width: 100vw would accomplish this

Comment: @David no exactly. I want this: when user resize browser window,  the content inside is scaled, so user would see whole content, but  scaled to less ration

Comment: @David basically i want to do this in pure js only, not using `transform` and other libs

Comment: Is using CSS an option? If so does width: 100vw solve your problem?

Comment: @David css is an option but it didnt work `<table style="width: 100vw;">`  it doesnt scale when i resize browser window

Comment: Sorry if I'm still misunderstanding the problem, is this not what you wanted https://jsfiddle.net/jdmscyp7/ ?

Comment: It resizes with the browsers works on most but not all browsers https://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units