# How can I scale my webpage proportionally using inner width to fit any display size?

Tags: javascript, css, scaling

I want to do the scaling depending on only width. I don't wanna mess with height. I have a website which unfortunately I made it for a way bigger display size. I didn't know how the adobe xd artboard size was too big. I thought it was 1920px but actually the width of my website is 3554px. I want to scale it down to fit smaller screens and scale it up for bigger screens. I can only make it fit in my laptop screen but I don't know the calculation behind for how to make it work for any screen. Basically I want scale to fit width and center the page horizontally. So everything is kinda based on width. The base width is 3554px. Please help me on how to do this using plain javascript?

Please check this link. Want to do something with plain javascript but using only width and keeping it at center position.
[Proportionally scale website to fit browser window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30115468/proportionally-scale-website-to-fit-browser-window)

CSS

```
#Web_1920__1 {
        position: absolute;
        width: 3554px;
        height: auto;
        border: 0px grey solid;
        background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0);
        overflow: visible;
        visibility: visible;
    }
```

This is the main div that should take the whole inner width.

JAVASCRIPT

```
const mypage = window.innerWidth;
document.getElementById("Web_1920__1").style.transform = "scale(0.432)";
document.getElementById("Web_1920__1").style.transformOrigin = "0% 0%";
```

I can get the inner width but those transform properties only work for my particular screen. How can I get the transform values dynamically to fit the page on any screen and keep it at the canter? No need to do anything with the height because there will be scrollbar.

Comment: You shouldn't use, scale for this purpose, You should probably use media query and set the correct width.

Comment: Does `width: 43.2vw;` help?

Comment: Abhay is correct. Scaling doesn’t add space around itself, the element just scales in place.

Comment: The page will resize proportionally when I resize the browser window. Using media query not working in my case. I will have to redesign every element because everything is based on big screen size.

Comment: Please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30115468/proportionally-scale-website-to-fit-browser-window

Comment: Try changing width from 3554px to 100%

Comment: I want to do something similar but depending on width only and with javascript.

Comment: @SoumyaRoy Then probably change the scale value to 

`document.getElementById("Web_1920__1").style.transform = "scale("+mypage/3554+")"`

Comment: Width 100% would work if other elements were % based. But unfortunately everything has position absolute and width is px based.

Comment: I see Soumya. Absolute positioning is great for certain things and not so great for others. This is a case where you should use flexbox or grid.

Comment: You don’t have to set width for them if you use flexbox or grid.

Comment: You can also give your elements a max-width so they don’t get bigger than you want.

Comment: Abhay Srivastav has kinda given what I want to achieve. I am checking it. But is it gonna keep it in center horizontally?

Comment: @SoumyaRoy assuming the element with the id `#Web_1920__1` is a block element, you can give it `margin: 0 auto;` to center. If its also an absolute element you can give it `left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, 0);` to stay centered. Both those solutions can center responsive elements.

Comment: Also with the solutions you are gonna use right now it might slow down your website quite a bit. First it renders elements in a big size (especially if you use images, this is bad) and after that it has to load and excecute javascript code. Besides that it might use alot of data for people that are not connected to wifi but to mobile data. Ofcourse this might not be an issue for you.

Comment: Abhay Srivastav's solution is working fine. I was trying to find an alternative solution like this. Of course nothing is perfect sometimes the code, sometimes the browser is messing up. But I was doing the scaling using web export plugin, which is getting slower after adding google adsense scripts. It's kina like the whole thousand line plugin code vs new 4-5 lines of code. I am aware of the slow performance issue. I am finding alternative solution to make it faster for better experience. You can suggest anything that might help to improve things.

Answer (score 0):

Abhay Srivastav's solution is working fine. A lot of thanks to him. The solution is like below. It's proportional scaling depending on width only. Everything will remain horizontally centered. Upscaling downscaling works for screen size. Window resize also works fine.

JAVASCRIPT

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', updateMe);
window.addEventListener('resize', updateMe);

function updateMe() 
{   
    const mypage = window.innerWidth;
    document.getElementById("Web_1920__1").style.transform = "scale("+mypage/3554+")";
    document.getElementById("Web_1920__1").style.transformOrigin = "0 0";
}
```

This piece of code can save you from putting additional thousand lines of plugin code. Page becomes lighter, loads faster and significant performance improvements.